# Regulating 220v AC voltage for halogen lamp with Arduino

Tags: voltage-regulator, ac, control

I am making a project based on Arduino which is about regulating the brightness of 220v AC halogen lamp. I've read that halogen lamps are the easiest ones to regulate the brightness. However, electronics is my weakest spot.

I've read that a TRIAC regulator can be used for this task, also from this other question ([220v AC Fan regulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/220v-ac-fan-regulator)) it seems that sometimes it wont work. Can it be used for my project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With mains power I'd always recommend buying a pre-made product to perform dimming. They should have taken care of key issues of safety such as isolation. Also the timing of Triac switching can be tricky in dimming applications when a micro is driving. So best to get tried and tested code.

[Here's an example](http://www.inmojo.com/store/inmojo-market/item/digital-ac-dimmer-module-lite-v.2/) including Arduino code. I haven't tried out this product but the low voltage is opto-isolated from the mains and the PCB appears to have physical separation between both voltage domains.